# dplyr::inner_join -- how to include certain observations even if they don't appear in both dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, inner-join

I have two dataframes that I want to merge by a common variable. Some observations appear in one data but not in the other, and vice verse. When merging, I want to keep only the observations that appear in both dataframes, and therefore `dplyr::inner_join()` is appropriate.

However, there's an exclusion. There are *some* observations that I'd like to include in the merged data no matter what. That is, even if they don't appear in both original dataframes. The indication to which ones are those "special" observations to keep is given as certain values in certain columns.

### Example

I want to merge the following dataframes (`df_population` and `df_gdp`)

**1. `df_population`**

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

## helper function
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

set.seed(2021)

df_population <-
  tribble(~country, ~population,
        "australia", 24.99,
        "united_kingdom", 66.65,
        "france", 66.99,
        "spain", 46.94,
        "canada", 37.59,
        "brazil", 209.5) %>%
  mutate(col_of_strings = c(myFun(5), "dont_leave_me_behind"))

## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   country        population col_of_strings      
##   <chr>               <dbl> <chr>               
## 1 australia            25.0 GLNWN9968R          
## 2 united_kingdom       66.6 FTELH3426F          
## 3 france               67.0 NFOSZ6335V          
## 4 spain                46.9 ZFGRD8875F          
## 5 canada               37.6 GFICE2875O          
## 6 brazil              210.  dont_leave_me_behind
```

**2. `df_gdp`**

```r
df_gdp <-
  tribble(~country, ~gdp_growth,
        "australia", 2.9,
        "united_kingdom", 1.4,
        "france", 1.7,
        "spain", 2.4,
        "canada", 1.9,
        "greece", 1.9) %>%
  mutate(col_of_strings = sample(c(myFun(5), "dont_leave_me_behind")))


## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   country        gdp_growth col_of_strings      
##   <chr>               <dbl> <chr>               
## 1 australia             2.9 dont_leave_me_behind
## 2 united_kingdom        1.4 RQHHI9679V          
## 3 france                1.7 PFSZX1552L          
## 4 spain                 2.4 BQTBY7537E          
## 5 canada                1.9 OECIK9698V          
## 6 greece                1.9 VXDQQ4718J
```

#### My Problem

Normally I'd go with

```r
dplyr::inner_join(df_population, df_gdp, by = "country")
```

But:
Although I want only the countries that are common to both dataframes, I still want to include any country that has `col_of_strings == dont_leave_me_behind`

I hope there's a simple solution to this. Thanks!

Comment: I would `full_join()` and then `filter()` the results.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your data to include rows that don't join correctly? As it stands, your "dont_leave_me_behind" rows *are* retained in the `inner_join`.

Comment: @M.Viking This would be one way. However, consider that real datasets I'm dealing with are more complex and much larger in size than here. So `full_join()` is going to be rather inefficient (computation-wise).

Comment: Is `country` the unique id field?

Comment: @r2evans, thanks. I've updated the dataframes. `country` is both unique and the common variable to merge by.

Comment: Nice of you to *not* use `set.seed(2020)` ... many have suggested that that is a *horrible* starting point of any stochastic process ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways come to mind.

1. Per @M.Viking's suggestion, `full_join` first and then filter.

   ```r
   dplyr::full_join(df_population, df_gdp, by = "country") %>%
     dplyr::filter(
       col_of_strings.y == "dont_leave_me_behind" | !is.na(col_of_strings.x),
       col_of_strings.x == "dont_leave_me_behind" | !is.na(col_of_strings.y)
     )
   # # A tibble: 6 x 5
   #   country        population col_of_strings.x     gdp_growth col_of_strings.y    
   #   <chr>               <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl> <chr>               
   # 1 australia            25.0 LQMPB3662R                  2.9 VKBCE2969H          
   # 2 united_kingdom       66.6 WDXVX4684T                  1.4 FMAKF4470M          
   # 3 france               67.0 VJHBH0078U                  1.7 dont_leave_me_behind
   # 4 spain                46.9 XFJPD7687T                  2.4 RMPYK2467U          
   # 5 canada               37.6 AQRCR0724P                  1.9 JXMMZ3736X          
   # 6 brazil              210.  dont_leave_me_behind       NA   <NA>
   ```
2. Do the inner join, extract missing rows from each frame, and `bind_rows` them back in. This steps requires some renaming because of the `.x`/`.y` names post-join.

   ```r
   tmp1 <- dplyr::inner_join(df_population, df_gdp, by = "country")

   missing_pop <- df_population %>%
     dplyr::filter(
       col_of_strings == "dont_leave_me_behind",
       !country %in% tmp1$country
     ) %>%
     dplyr::rename(col_of_strings.x = col_of_strings)
   missing_pop
   # # A tibble: 1 x 3
   #   country population col_of_strings.x    
   #   <chr>        <dbl> <chr>               
   # 1 brazil        210. dont_leave_me_behind

   missing_gdp <- df_gdp %>%
     dplyr::filter(
       col_of_strings == "dont_leave_me_behind",
       !country %in% tmp1$country
     ) %>%
     dplyr::rename(col_of_strings.y = col_of_strings)
   missing_gdp
   # # A tibble: 0 x 3
   # # ... with 3 variables: country <chr>, gdp_growth <dbl>, col_of_strings.y <chr>

   out <- dplyr::bind_rows(tmp1, missing_pop, missing_gdp)
   out
   # # A tibble: 6 x 5
   #   country        population col_of_strings.x     gdp_growth col_of_strings.y    
   #   <chr>               <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl> <chr>               
   # 1 australia            25.0 LQMPB3662R                  2.9 VKBCE2969H          
   # 2 united_kingdom       66.6 WDXVX4684T                  1.4 FMAKF4470M          
   # 3 france               67.0 VJHBH0078U                  1.7 dont_leave_me_behind
   # 4 spain                46.9 XFJPD7687T                  2.4 RMPYK2467U          
   # 5 canada               37.6 AQRCR0724P                  1.9 JXMMZ3736X          
   # 6 brazil              210.  dont_leave_me_behind       NA   <NA>
   ```
3. Similar to 2, but using `anti_join`:

   ```r
   tmp1 <- dplyr::inner_join(df_population, df_gdp, by = "country")
   out <- dplyr::bind_rows(
     tmp1,
     dplyr::filter(df_population, col_of_strings == "dont_leave_me_behind") %>%
       dplyr::anti_join(., tmp1, by = "country") %>%
       dplyr::rename(col_of_strings.x = col_of_strings),
     dplyr::filter(df_gdp, col_of_strings == "dont_leave_me_behind") %>%
       anti_join(., tmp1, by = "country") %>%
       dplyr::rename(col_of_strings.y = col_of_strings)
   )
   ```

The latter two perform about the same with benchmarking:

```r
bench::mark(full1=..., inner2=..., inner3=...)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory
#   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>
# 1 full1       5.83ms  7.72ms     127.     1.36KB     4.32    59     2      463ms <tibb~ <Rpro~
# 2 inner2      9.54ms 11.46ms      84.9   11.28KB     2.07    41     1      483ms <tibb~ <Rpro~
# 3 inner3     13.95ms 14.92ms      62.9   11.28KB     4.49    28     2      445ms <tibb~ <Rpro~
# # ... with 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

where the `full_join` works much better *in this case*. Larger data *may* perform significantly differently, I haven't tested it yet.